# Remote access solution for active and inactive sessions

Tags: kde, remote-desktop, remote-access, terminal-server, desktop-sharing

I am running some Kubuntu 18.04 systems. I would like to to install a remote access software on these systems that allows accessing the systems from other Linux systems.

Does a free software exist that allows desktop sharing AND terminal server operation? I.e. a software that can do both:

1. Run before log-in, allowing to start a new desktop session on a
   computer where the specified user has not logged-in and has no active
   desktop session running.
2. Share an existing desktop session if the specified user already is logged in.

Comment: @user68186 I can't see where this answers my question.

Comment: @mikewhatever Thanks, my question is covered there. But the accepted answer essentially says there is only a free-for-3-users solution. Also I guess things have changed since 2011, so I can not be sure there is a better solution today.

Comment: Several solutions are mentioned there. If one does not suit your needs, just use another. To make an informed choice, you are more then welcome to research at least some of the solutions.

Comment: x11vnc meets both your conditions. It lets you login to your remote desktop. It also lets your access if you have an existing desktop session.

Comment: @mikewhatever: Thanks, I will do so. However I read a lot before asking here and (maybe due to my limited knowledge) it was very hard to find out if a software supports 1. or 2. or both. I had the impression that the experts take that information as granted and so do not mention it explicitely.